# Use Ctrl+/ as shortcut in Delphi program

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, shortcut

Is this even possible? Notepad++ for example does it, but simply trying to assign it to components like actions or menu items doesn't work. The event it is assigned to simply doesn't trigger.

So, I took my question to Google. Nada. Then, I tried stepping through the various shortcut functions, in this case TextToShortCut and ShortCutToText.

The first one, TextToShortCut, converts stuff like 'Ctrl+A' (a string) to the following 16bit value:

```
(uint)A | (uint)Ctrl
```

Works fine, mostly. However, I observed the following weirdness:

```
// Try converting back and forward...
TextToShortCut('Ctrl+/') = 16495

// That's incorrect. It should be:
Ord('/') or scCtrl = 16431

// Incorrect too
ShortCutToText(16495) = 'Ctrl+/'

// This is the shortcut the first line actually creates (Ctrl+o)
Ord('o') or scCtrl = 16495 // wut?

// Which is invalid, cause only caps are used
ShortCutToText(16431) = ''
```

What's going on here? For now, I believe the error lies in the final part of TextToShortCut: after handling the part before the + sign ("Ctrl" in this case), it will try to find a shortcut for the remaining part ("/"). **However, in its current form the part after + must be a valid shortcut on its own too.**

```
for Key := $08 to $255 do { Copy range from table in ShortCutToText }
  if AnsiCompareText(Text, ShortCutToText(Key)) = 0 then
  begin
    Result := Key or Shift;
    Exit;
  end;
```

So, because:

```
ShortCutToText('/') = 0 (failure)
MapVirtualKey('/',MAPVK_VK_TO_VSC) = 0 (failure)
```

... the loop fails to detect '/' as a valid shortcut.

Is this some VCL bug or am I missing something?

Here's a proof of concept (yes, I'm taking screenshots of code, but mashing this together with the Component Palette is faster than using this code directly):

**Edit 1:**

[image]

**Edit 2:**

Manually assigning 16431 to the menu item does not work.

Comment: Works fine here. Although only on the `/` key that is part of the numpad. But then that's what npp does. Its restore zoom shortcut is mapped to `Ctrl+Num /`

Comment: Notepad++ uses the regular one (left of Shift on US International) for stepping to the beginning of the word at the caret too.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you assign an `OnShortCut` event handler to your menu's parent `TForm`, you will see that pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> results in a `TShortCut` value of 16575 from `Menus.ShortCutFromMessage()`, which is the function that the VCL uses internally when dispatching keystrokes for shortcut handling.

Both `ShortCutToText(16495)` and `ShortCutToText(16575)` return `'Ctrl+/'`, so lets break it down:

```
scCtrl = $4000
16495 = $406F
16575 = $40BF
```

Both shortcuts have the `scCtrl` flag present.

`ShortCutToText($6F)` and `ShortCutToText($BF)` both return `'/'`. This is because `MapVirtualKey()` returns the same scan code ($350000) for both virtual keys `$6F` (`VK_DIVIDE`) and `$BF` (`VK_OEM_2` - the `/?` key for US keyboards).

When dispatching a shortcut, the VCL does exact comparisons of `TShortCut` values.  So when you have 16495 assigned as your shortcut, it will not trigger because the system is reporting a shortcut of 16575 instead, even though they both map to `Ctrl+/`.

When I assign 16575 to the `ShortCut` property of a `TMenuItem` or `TAction`, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> triggers the item, as expected.

So the trick is that the system is reporting a shortcut that uses the `VK_OEM_2` virtual key for `/`, but you are expecting it to use the `VK_DIVIDE` virtual key instead.

Answer (score 7):

A simple investigation of `Key` from an `OnKeyDown` event handler shows two different kind of forward slashes:

- `/` on the numerical keypad = `111` (combined with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> = `16575`)
- `/` next to the shift key = `191` (combined with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> = `16495`)

It is not possible to create a single shortcut which responds to both.

But instead of setting the shortcut on the memu item, you could attach an action which has a `SecondaryShortCuts` property. Then use:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Action1.ShortCut := 16575;
  Action1.SecondaryShortCuts.Add('Ctrl+/');
end;
```

Comment: There's always the SecondaryShortCuts property

Comment: I'm not trying to bind to both, I'm just trying to bind to the 191 one. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: *I'm just trying to bind to the 191 one.*  Why doesn't the question state that?  Are we meant to guess?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I completely forgot about the existence of the Numpad version of / when I wrote it. Sorry about that.

Comment: That's understandable. But your comment doesn't sound very grateful. *Thanks for answering though*. But what you did not like about the answer was really a result of that omission. I guess that's why I reacted. Sticking up for my fellow answerer!!